# Run Python 64bit In 32Bit mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Note: Running windows7X64**

I want to use some audio functions I have seen allot for python 2.7 like snack and such, however I'm using python 3.3. I have come across pygame.py that has some audio functions however pygame doesn't support 64bit arch yet.

So can it be done? if not do we know of any python audio integration modules that can get the job done on python 3 with a 64bit arch

Yes I can just install python 3 32bit but that seems counterproductive and unnecessarily complicated.

Thanks 
Ben

Comment: You need to install 32-bit Python if you need to use 32-bit extension modules.

Comment: Ok, if that's the only option am I able to have python 32bit and 64bit installed or will that cause issues ?

Comment: Wow, how did you know to look there lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to install 32-bit Python to run 32-bit extension modules. In my experience, two Python installations can live side-by-side quite nicely on Windows, as long as you make sure your environment (`PYTHONPATH` esp.) is set properly.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
$ defaults write com.apple.versioner.python Prefer-32-Bit -bool yes
```

Edit: For the sake of sharing information, this will work (at least from my experience) on a Mac; however, it will not work on a Windows.

Comment: Oopz sorry i should have specified, i'm on a windows system atm.